# avr linker++ setting header and .cpp files

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, optimization, arduino

I want to set the linker correctly so an eclipse project can work properly.I have added the the folder that my header and cpp files exist to the c/c++ compiler directories. I have to set the linker also. I do n ot know how cause the linker in the tool settings wants to add a library (an .a file that does not exist cause none makes it), so since i do not have any .a file i get error at the functions cause i can give the folder path to the linker but inside there there is no .a file. What can i do.

Comment: What `.a` file? Maybe you're talking about the C++ standard library?

Comment: at the avr linker++ for an arduino project it has added the path for the lib and at the name section it gives the name of the .a file that exist in the path. I have only .h and .cpp files i do not have other type of files/libraries. I just want to add these files from another project without coping them inside the same project

Comment: It would help to know what `.a` file you're looking for

Comment: i think is the c++ standard library as H2C03. Indexer in arduino project have already added a library.In order this to happen it needs to set the path of the library and the name.This is the name of the file with extention .a . My problem is that i do not have and i do not make an .a files cause i only want to link a .cpp file